# How to use SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL?

Tags: sql-server

We have set of around 50 sql select queries, most of them are complex involving 5 or 6 tables in the joins. They are only select queries to get the data for producing reports. All of them already went to through a clear testing. Now we are requested to add `WITH (NOLOCK)` to every tables in all the fifty queries. Instead of adding NOLOCK in every individual tables. Is it ok If I just add `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` at the top of each select query?

We are not allowed to stored procedure and we aren't using `BEGIN TRANS` `COMMIT TRANS`, Just adding  `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` as a first line, will it work like using `NOLOCK`? Also what is the scope level of setting transaction isolation level? 
I am worried about affecting the way other applications communicating the same DB. is it right that once the query finished executed, Isolation level fall back to its default value??

Comment: re-tagged with `sql-server` because of `with (nolock)` in the question.